# ECS Service different tasks in same task group

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have ECS cluster with 20 equal instances. I run there three services.

1. First service is run as Daemon (it might be a hack but what I actually want is to have as many task instances as many ec2 instances I have). This service has ~60% of memory available.
2. Second ECS Service has desired count 8 instances and memory assignment is ~30%.
3. Third ECS service has desired count only 2 instances and memory assignment is also ~30%.

What happens time to time is that Second and Third service gets scheduled on 1 EC2 instance so they occupies ~60% which means that First service cannot be placed here and I get errors in ECS.

How can I make sure that Second and Third service tasks are never run on same EC2 so there is always enough remaining resources for the First daemon service? I found TaskGroups but I was not able to utilize them when my tasks are managed by Service.

Comment: How did you mange to achieve this?